# What is a dictionary that gives descriptions instead of definitions called?

Tags: single-word-requests, dictionaries

In Collins Dictionary if you search for a word, it gives you a description of the word, not a definition. Like "if someone is *rueful* he express..."

Is there any term for this kind of dictionary? Like there are *context* dictionaries.

I tried to google "descriptive dictionary", but nothing appeared. How do I find such dictionaries for other languages?

Comment: The excellent [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/dictionary/Major-dictionaries) article on **dictionaries** doesn't seem to include a specific term. The term 'conceptual dictionary', using a technique pioneered by Bishop John Wilkins and famously employed by Roget, does appear. But these don't give explanatory statements, just lists of synonyms / classmates (eg cutlery...knife...fork...).

Comment: I think Edwin is right and there's no such term, yet…

Given that we have plenty of illustrated dictionaries, and dictionaries with illustrative entries, would it be too much to invent the new category, illustrative dictionary?

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest "encyclopedia" ... but I won't.

Comment: Dictionary of English usage, maybe?

Comment: @StuartF I glad you brought it up, never heard about such dictionaries. I checked Webster's dictionary of English usage, but it is rather not an option. For some words it provides cases *when this word is used", but for most words content consists of this: (screenshot) https://imgur.com/a/3SZ9FMO

Comment: @HotLicks it is wit idea! But I don't see Wikipedia having entries for words like "amazing", "sad", "condemn", etc... (